# Pyspark : The evaluation in the cross validation based on a user-defined metric

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-ml

I am a newbie in Spark . I installed PySpark 2.3.0 on Windows. I am working on a dataset that contains 3 classes : "Positive","Negative","Neutral".

I want to apply cross validation using LinearSVC , but for evaluation I want to use the average F1-score for the 2 classes "positive" and "negative" only to evaluate each model.

In the following code :

I think that , by choosing the "metricName" to be "f1" in the "MulticlassClassificationEvaluator" , the best parameters are chosen based on the average F1-score of the 3 classes .. But as I said before , I want the choice to be based on the average score of 2 classes only.

```
from pyspark.ml.tuning import CrossValidator, ParamGridBuilder
from pyspark.ml.classification import LinearSVC
from pyspark.ml.evaluation import MulticlassClassificationEvaluator

LSVC = LinearSVC()
paramGrid = ParamGridBuilder().addGrid(LSVC.maxIter, [10, 100, 1000]).addGrid(LSVC.regParam, [0.01,0.1,10.0,100.0]).build()
crossval = CrossValidator(estimator=LSVC,
                      #estimator=pipeline,
                      estimatorParamMaps=paramGrid,
                      evaluator=MulticlassClassificationEvaluator(metricName="f1"),
                      numFolds=2)
```